# Rename column name using laravel migration using doctrine/dbal gives error

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine

Im trying to rename a database column in my localhost so that i can later do it in development and production

Im using laravel 5 and installed doctrine dbal.

Code of my migration:

```
    $table->renameColumn('puesto', 'aux');
```

After I run `php artisan migrate` it tells me that

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                         
Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSqlPlatform may not support it.
```

The column im trying to rename isnt even json, although there are json column in the table, in fact only one called 'alianzas'. 
My question is, how can i rename the columns from the migration and not manually in the database.

Comment: why you're installed doctrine when Laravel have it's own great [migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations)?

Comment: laravel documentation asks you to install doctrine if you are going to rename columns http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#renaming-columns

Comment: Im using laravel 5 and when i went through composer.json to see if the dependency was included it didnt show up so i added it. Either way i tried the same code before installing doctrine and the error was different, it was `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver' not found` so i thought it was the dependency after all

Comment: did you install doctrine/dbal with composer for the project?

Answer (score 11):

It looks like `laravel` only suggests the install.

You can install it with:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Answer (score 9):

**Modifying Columns**

Prerequisites

Before modifying a column, be sure to add the **doctrine/dbal** dependency to your ***composer.json*** file. The Doctrine DBAL library is used to determine the current state of the column and create the SQL queries needed to make the specified adjustments to the column.

```
"require": {
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5"
},

composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Updating Column Attributes

The change method allows you to modify an existing column to a new type, or modify the column's attributes. For example, you may wish to increase the size of a string column. To see the change method in action, let's increase the size of the name column from 25 to 50:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('name', 50)->change();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This error still occurs in Laravel 5.1, even when `doctrine/dbal` is installed.

As a temporary workaround, you could write your migration in raw SQL like so:

```
public function up(){
  DB::statement("ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME puesto TO aux");
}
```

Comment: This throws an error with newer versions of MySQL. The correct syntax to rename an integer column from `a` to `b` is:

`ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE a b INTEGER;`

Comment: What if the column you're altering is in a different database, not the default?

Comment: You should be able to specify the connection to use with `DB::connection('other-database')->statement(…);`. It's been a while since I wrote this answer though and it seems that there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use DB statement if you don't want to use doctrine

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE puesto aux VARCHAR(200) ');
}
```